# Regex to transform all rem-calc in pixels

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I have to port some sass to css and I have thousands of rem-calc declarations.

So I need for example `rem-calc(10 15 20 15);` to be `10px 15px 20px 15px;`

Started with `/rem-calc\([1-9]/` but don't know how to approach it. If some of the regex experts could help

Test case samples:

```
  padding: rem-calc(10 15 20 15);
  width: rem-calc(415);
```

Should become:

```
padding: 10px 15px 20px 15px;
width: 415px;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just match and capture these numbers with [`rem-calc\((.*)\);`](https://regex101.com/r/zW6fB4/1) and then split the Group 1 contents with  a space. See https://jsfiddle.net/348dc6b9/

Comment: Since you have SASS, why not compile it and took generated CSS?

Comment: @Justinas because it compiles to em.

Comment: anyway  @WiktorStribiżew idea worked very well. thanks

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you submit it as an answer? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a rough idea: if you match these `rem-calc` strings with `/rem-calc\((.*)\);/` regex and then grab Group 1 value to split with spaces and add `px`, then it willl look like

```
var re = /rem-calc\((.*)\);/g;
var str = 'rem-calc(10 15 20 15);';
var m = str.match(re);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1].split(/\s*(\d+)\s*/).filter(Boolean).join("px ") + "px");
}
```

The `/\s*(\d+)\s*/` splits with digits enclosed with whitespaces, then `.filter(Boolean)` removes empty values and `join("px ")` adds `px` after the digits. Then, we need to append `px`  at the end.